# Notation $A_q^{2|0}$ and $A_q^{0|2}$ in Manin's book.

Tags: representation-theory, noncommutative-algebra, quantum-groups, noncommutative-geometry

In Manin's book: [quantum groups and non-commutative geometry](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/2921120003), there are two notations $A_q^{2|0}$ and $A_q^{0|2}$. Here
$$
A_q^{2|0} = k<x,y>/(xy-q^{-1}yx), \\
A_q^{0|2} = k<\xi,\eta>/(\xi^2, \eta^2, \xi \eta + q \eta \xi).
$$
Why he used $0, 2$? Are there some special meaning of $0, 2$? Is $A_q^{0|2}$ dual to $A_q^{2|0}$ is some sense? Thank you very much.

Comment: One is the Kozsul dual of the other, perhaps?

Comment: This related to the usual notation of coordinates in a supersymmetric space together with a $q$ factor (to twist the commutation). Just put $q = 1$ and you will see that the first have two bosonic coordinates while the second have two fermionic coordinates.